# Command \hypersetup{colorlinks=true} changes color of section header

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I have a `beamer` presentation, and I found some code to make a slide with just the section title at the start of each section.  When I add `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}` at the beginning, the color of these section titles change.  Maybe they're somehow interpreted as links?

With `colorlinks=true`, we get the following:

[image: with colorlinks=true]

With `colorlinks=false`, we get the following:
[image: with colorlinks=false]

So I guess `hyperref` is making these section titles into links, and then coloring them.  How do I prevent that?  Or at least get the coloring right?

The code:

```
\documentclass[english,aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\definecolor{BBGblue}{RGB}{13,157,219}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=BBGblue}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Want this to be BBGblue}
\begin{frame}{This is blue -- good}
\end{frame}

\section{This should be BBGblue too}
\begin{frame}{This is blue too}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "color-hammer", the `hyperref` option `allcolors=BBGblue` like this:

```
\documentclass[english,aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=BBGblue, % All links are colored in BBGblue
  allcolors=BBGblue % change all colors to blue ... <===================
}

\definecolor{BBGblue}{RGB}{13,157,219}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=BBGblue}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Want this to be BBGblue}
\begin{frame}{This is blue -- good}
\end{frame}

\section{This should be BBGblue too}
\begin{frame}{This is blue too}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with the wished result:

[image]

Comment: Ah.  I want the section titles to be BBGblue, but I still want \href's a different color, so we can tell they're links.  I guess the issue is that the section titles are also links -- so how to treat them differently?

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily switch off the link colouring by using `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` in front of `\insertsectionhead`.

```
\documentclass[english,aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\definecolor{BBGblue}{RGB}{13,157,219}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=BBGblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=BBGblue}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}%
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
    \insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Want this to be BBGblue}
\begin{frame}{This is blue -- good}
\end{frame}

\section{This should be BBGblue too}
\begin{frame}{This is blue too}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh this is a great solution too.  Thank you!