# Beamer - Change section font color while using hyperref

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I'm using the hyperreff in this configuration:

```
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks = true,
     urlcolor = blue}
```

And the beaver color theme:

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

The problem is that because the header is red and the section is considered a link, the section title gets almost invisible:
[image]

I want to force the color of the section to be gray (only the section, not of the other links), but I'm not managing to do it while keeping the hyperref active, there is a way to do it?

Comment: Show a complete example, that can be used for test.

Comment: I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396694) question will solve your problem, please see. and for [colorlinks=true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50747/options-for-appearance-of-links-in-hyperref/50754#50754)